# How can I extract values from graph in R?

Tags: r, rstudio

As you know, Our country is famous for the popular music industry, named "K-POP".

Recently, the 'tuneR' package to analyze 'wav.file' was released in R.

So I want to know any tendency of the K-POP musics and cluster them by using this package.

In analysis, I got a graph to show the notes of a music file (see example below)

[image]

My problem is that I don't know how can I extract the peak value's notes from this graph (those circled in blue)

Please let me know some methods if you know any functions to resolve this problem in R.

```
library("tuneR")

transcribeMusic <- function(wavFile, widthSample = 4096, expNotes = NULL)
{
perioWav <- periodogram(wavFile, width = widthSample)
freqWav <- FF(perioWav)
noteWav <- noteFromFF(freqWav) 
melodyplot(perioWav, observed = noteWav, expected = expNotes, plotenergy = FALSE)
}

songHlp <- readMP3("Beenzino.mp3")
testSound_stereo <- extractWave(songHlp, from = 0, to = 12, xunit = "time")
testSound <- mono(testSound_stereo, "both")
transcribeMusic(testSound)
```

Comment: It's unclear to me what exactly you want to extract. Perhaps the results from your file look very different than the results of the test file I used. Perhaps you can post a link to the image you are creating and clearly indicate (perhaps with hand drawn annotation) exactly what you want to extract. I can be pretty sure the "graph" isn't going to be helpful for extracting the data. Any patterns you may see in a plot must be characterized and extract in the data you pass to the plot.

Comment: Objects of class Wave have multiple slots, including `left` and `right` channel vectors (pg 50 of the PDF manual). You can extract numerical values from those channel vectors and get peaks that way.